# Look up multiple words in a large string, with each word being at most k words apart from another word

Tags: python, algorithm, sliding-window

Imagine you are given a long string of `text` - for e.g. "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and lorem ipsum etc", and then you are given an array of `words` like `["quick", "brown"]`, and an int `k`. How do I write a `query` function which return to me a range defined by `start` and `end` in the long string `text` where `text[start]` and `text[end]` are both words in `words`, and within `start` and `end` in text, all of the words in `words` occur, at most `k` words apart?

I expect to run this `query` function multiple times for a given long string `text`, so I'm hoping for an algorithm that is `O(f + s + t + ...)` where `f` is the number of occurrences of the first word in `words` in `text`, `s` is the number of occurrences of the second word in `words` in `text` and so forth.

What I have is the following -

```py
def query(text: str, words: list, k: int):
    word2idx_list = get_word2idx_list(text)

def get_word2idx_list(
    text: str,
):
    word2idx_list = defaultdict(list)
    words = text.split(" ")
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        word2idx_list[word].append(i)
    return dict(word2idx_list)
```

but after this I get stuck - do I use a sliding window?

Comment: Some examples of input and output would be helpful here. Can you write any algorithm that accomplishes this, perhaps a brute force one that doesn't yet meet your time complexity bounds?

Comment: Also, any algorithm will have a time complexity at least linear in the length of `text` and/or in the length of `words`, since you'll probably want to be able to read the input you're given. Or are you ignoring preprocessing time for the text, if that's irrelevant?

Comment: Don't understand what you are looking for, pls post some examples

Answer (score 0):

**algorithm sketch**

- inputs:

  - `k = 1`  # max separation between words
  - `haystack = 'the quick ... lorem ipsum'.split()`
  - `needles = set('dog fox lazy'.split())`
- state:

  - `candidates = set()`  # tuples of 1 or more word indexes

We win if we ever discover a tuple s.t. `len(candidate) == len(needles)`.

1st invariant: For each index `i` stored within each of the candidates, it will be the case that `haystack[i] in needles`.

2nd invariant: When scanning a `sorted(candidate)`, distance between adjacent indexes will be at most `k`.

**preprocessing**

To get the ball rolling, do a linear scan over the haystack. At each index we

- ask whether `haystack[i] in needles`
- if so, insert several 1-tuples:

  - `for j in range(i - k, i + k + 1):`

    - `candidates.add((j,))`

**winnow candidates**

Now expand those candidates.

- while there are candidates of length less than `len(needles)`:

  - choose an arbitrary `candidate`, removing it from the set
  - `lo = min(candidate) - k`
  - `hi = max(candidate) + k`
  - make a temporary `ndls = needles.copy()`
  - `for i in candidate:`

    - `ndls.remove(haystack[i])`
  - Is `ndls` empty? Oh, good, we're done! Report the match.
  - At this point, `ndls` has words we seek within the `lo` .. `hi` range.
  - `for i in range(lo, hi + 1):`

    - `if haystack[i] in ndls:`

      - `for j in range(i - k, i + k + 1):`

        - `candidates.add(candidate + (j,))`

So we have removed one candidate,
and optionally added candidates which increment its length.

Handwaving: I have ignored running off the left / right sides of the haystack.
Add a range() helper, or
consider padding both sides with `k` sentinel words which will never appear as a needle.

---

It's easy to exit early if only 1st match is needed.

To report all matches, keep looping until set of candidates is empty.
Its size *will* go to zero, even if there's no valid matches.

If there are H haystack words and N needles,
then it costs O(N) to construct the needle set
and O(H) for the preprocessing scan.
After that the match rate will dominate,
with worst case cost of `O(k × N)`
which you might view as `O(N)`.
That's for a haystack largely composed of repeated copies of the needle set, but you wouldn't need a fancy algorithm for such an input.
Realistic inputs will see a running time proportional to number of candidates generated, which depends on both `k` and the match rate.

---

**alternate algorithm**

Here's a much simpler approach that doesn't
follow the distance requirement you outlined,
but might suit your needs.

- `needles = { word: -math.inf for word in 'dog fox lazy'.split() }`
- `for i, word in enumerate(haystack):`

  - `if word in needles:`

    - `needles[word] = i`
    - `if min(needles.values()) >= i - k:`

      - report a match!

Consider post-processing those reported matches
if too-wide gaps between needles will pose a problem,
perhaps by examining `sorted(needles.values())` deltas.